# Problem with parsing javascript file marked as Shebang

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babel-loader, craco

I have a react app where I wanted to import a javascript file from a third-party library but file is mark with shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node`.

I found (e.g. here [How to Configure Webpack with Shebang Loader to Ignore Hashbang Importing Cesium React Component into Typescript React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890997/how-to-configure-webpack-with-shebang-loader-to-ignore-hashbang-importing-cesium)) I can load file by overriding webpack configuration and adding a new loader shebang-loader (I also have tried shebang-loader2) but overriding webpack in react app is recommended only with @craco/craco so I added it to package.json and tried add loader to existing webpack-config.js.

I produced this lines of code. File craco.config.js:

```
const throwError = (message) =>
throwUnexpectedConfigError({
    packageName: 'craco',
    githubRepo: 'gsoft-inc/craco',
    message,
    githubIssueQuery: 'webpack',
});
module.exports = {
webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, {paths}) => {

        const shebangLoader =   { test: /node_modules\/npm-groovy-lint\/lib\/groovy-lint.js$/, loader: "shebang-loader" }

        const {isAdded: shebangLoaderIsAdded1} = addAfterLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName('url-loader'), shebangLoader);
        if (!shebangLoaderIsAdded1) throwError('failed to add shebang-loader');

        return webpackConfig;
    },
},
```

};

It resolves problem with shebang and it ignores `#!/usr/bin/env node` but now I still get error

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:16)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/shebang2-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| const { getSourceLines, isErrorInLogLevelScope } = require("./utils");
| class NpmGroovyLint {
>     "use strict";
|     options = {}; // NpmGroovyLint options
|     args = []; // Command line arguments
```

It looks like it does not recognise *"use strict"* line.
Can anyone put some suggestions what should be a problem ?

Comment: Did you try following [these installation instructions for shebang2-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shebang2-loader)? In particular, add a regular rule, after your babel-loader rule.

Comment: Yes, I did. In Craco config I added loader after babel-loader. Snippet of the code:
        
const {isAdded: shebangLoaderIsAdded1} = addAfterLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName('babel-loader'), shebangLoader);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of investigation, I have finally come to a resolution. Firstly I have to say that there is no option to use NpmGroovyLint in react-like applications that run in browsers because after I resolved mentioned problem up here I figured that NpmGroovyLint uses node libraries as perf_hooks which are not available in a browser enviroment.

But I can post code that resolves the problem described in my question. It was needed to add a plugin to babel-loader named 'plugin-proposal-class-properties'. Here is my snipped of craco config. You can use it as a recipe occasionally.

```
const {addAfterLoader, getLoaders, loaderByName, removeLoaders, throwUnexpectedConfigError} = require('@craco/craco');
const throwError = (message) =>
throwUnexpectedConfigError({
    packageName: 'craco',
    githubRepo: 'gsoft-inc/craco',
    message,
    githubIssueQuery: 'webpack',
});
module.exports = {
webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, {paths}) => {
        const {hasFoundAny, matches} = getLoaders(webpackConfig, loaderByName('babel-loader'));
        if (!hasFoundAny) throwError('failed to find babel-loader');

        const {hasRemovedAny, removedCount} = removeLoaders(webpackConfig, loaderByName('babel-loader'));
        if (!hasRemovedAny) throwError('no babel-loader to remove');
        if (removedCount !== 2) throwError('had expected to remove 2 babel loader instances');

        //add plugin proposal class properties to existing babel loader
        const propClassOptions = {...matches[1].loader.options, ...{plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]}};
        const propClassLoader = {...matches[1].loader, ...{options: propClassOptions}};
        const babelLoaderWithPropClassPlugin = {...matches[1], ...{loader: propClassLoader}};

        const shebangLoader = {
            test: /node_modules\/npm-groovy-lint\/lib\/groovy-lint.js$/,
            use: [{loader: 'shebang2-loader'}, {...{loader: require.resolve('babel-loader')}, ...{options: propClassOptions}}]
        }

        const {isAdded: babelLoaderWithPropClassIsAdded} = addAfterLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName('url-loader'), matches[0].loader);
        if (!babelLoaderWithPropClassIsAdded) throwError('failed to add ts-loader');

        const {isAdded: babelLoaderIsAdded} = addAfterLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName('babel-loader'), babelLoaderWithPropClassPlugin.loader);
        if (!babelLoaderIsAdded) throwError('failed to add back babel-loader for non-application JS');

        const {isAdded: shebangLoaderIsAdded1} = addAfterLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName('url-loader'), shebangLoader);
        if (!shebangLoaderIsAdded1) throwError('failed to add shebang-loader');

        return webpackConfig;
    },
},
};
```